# Параллельное программирование в c#

Tags: c#, tpl, распараллеливание, plinq

У меня такая задача - сначала программа забирает с сайта информацию, затем ее обрабатывает и выводит на экран. Проблема в том, что эти действия производятся с нескольких сайтов и хотелось бы распараллелить их, чтобы сайты обрабатывались одновременно, а не один за другим. Посоветуйте, какими инструментами и технологиями это лучше сделать и подходит ли здесь TPL и PLINQ? Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: [Когда использовать Parallel.ForEach, а когда PLINQ](http://habrahabr.ru/post/135942/)

Comment: Прочитал статью и все равно непонятно, как мне использовать PLINQ. У меня есть три различных метода и они выполняются для нескольких сайтов. Сами методы выполняются последовательно, но нужно чтобы для каждого сайта эта группа методов выполнялась параллельно. Как я понял, для использования PLINQ нужно иметь коллекцию или даже тип, имплементирующий интерфейс IEnumerable,а у меня тут даже коллекции нет. Поправьте меня, если я не так понял.

Comment: Можно поступить по разному (как и всегда). Например, может сделать коллекцию методов из этих трёх методов?

Comment: Коллекцию методов? И так тоже можно?=)Если можно, немного поподробнее об этом

Comment: Вы можете сделать метод, который вызывает все три Ваших метода, и запустить его в параллельном режиме.

Comment: В ответе @Spectre метод как раз принимает коллекцию методов (массив в данном случае; там еще params, но это уже детали). Что-то подобное я и имел в виду:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> У меня есть три различных метода и они выполняются для нескольких сайтов

Тогда вам в самый раз использовать [Parallel.Invoke](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ParallelInvoke.aspx)(эта статья ознакомительная, но с лёгкостью гуглиться куда больше информации)

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    ()=> StartWorkWithFirstSite(),
    ()=> StartWorkWithSecondSite(),    
    ()=> StartWorkWithThirdSite(),
)
```

И конечно же это не единственный способ, ещё есть [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd235608.aspx) со своими Task`ами, и классические Thread`ы, и асинхронные делегаты, и прочее...